# How can I use RPi2 only to download Steam games?

Tags: windows

Is there a way to install Steam in a RPi2 and use the client just to download (Windows) games to a external hard disk?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this myself and it seems that you currently cant download steam onto a raspberry pi in the first place. I have tried manually installing the packages that make up the SteamOS but it requires too much processing power. The most i have been able to do is get the R-pi2 running as a cheep steam box but as for downloading games it seems to be a impossibility for now, until they bring out ARM support.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in theory, as an application doesn't necessarily need ARM support to run on an ARM device, as long as it has Linux support. However, in practice, the processing speed of the Pi is too low to do anything meaningful. Unless, of course, you love playing games at 0.1FPS. But even then you can only play Linux supporting games. Maybe try a small $150 PC instead..

Comment: It's explicitely asked to "just download" not to game. I take it that the games are supposed to be used on a windows PC later on.

Comment: @Ghanima ah, sorry. Wasn't paying utmost attention. In that case, probably not, don't know a way.

Comment: What about building a VM with a Windows version and install steam there? Would it work?

Comment: @Naschtok you could try.... But it may be too complex for the ARM processor

Comment: Maybe Windows 10 iot would work instead?

Comment: @Naschtok Windows IOT is only a bare OS, no GUI or anything. You'd need to make the GUI yourself.